# Can AWS Lambda trigger Powerautomate Flow?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, power-automate

What I like to achieve is to have my AWS Lambda script to trigger MS Powerautomate flow (like a connection to MS teams or Excel). Is this possible?

I seem to eye the trigger "When a HTTP request is received" in Powerautomate as possible route  but I'm still not sure.

Comment: Yes, of course it can.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Power Automate [HTTP triggers](https://powerautomate.microsoft.com/fr-fr/blog/call-flow-restapi/) and call the trigger endpoint via an AWS Lambda function.